# Dividing an attribute and creating a dataframe from it in R

Tags: r, computer-science, data-mining

I am stuck at a question in R hope anyone can help me. 
I have a training datset that has multiple attributes. Income is the attribute that has an classes <=50 and >50.
I need to create a new training dataset that has equal representation of both classes; i.e., number of observations of class “<=50K”
must be the same as number of observations of class “>50K”. Then I need to call this new training dataset.

```
indx <- sample(1:nrow(adult.train), 15000)
train <- adult.train[-indx, ]
test <- adult.train[indx, ]
```

But this only divides my dataset into 2 sets and not dividing them according to class.I am only required to use **sample** function  on
the majority class to sample as many observations as there are in the minority class.

Comment: You don't want to use any package for this ?

Comment: Literally dozens of ways to do this, including: [`by`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html), [`split`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html), [`dplyr::group_by`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html), and even plain old indexing with [`[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). You can start by splitting your frame into two frames based on "Income", and using your `indx` method on each of them.